# How to get Facebook news feed (fan page) for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Just read Fb documentarians and didn't found much on how to get news feed post to display on my iOS app (news feed from public fb Fan page).

Wondering if it's possible to retrieve data from Facebook? or it's better to parse data of it..

Has anyone done this in iOS? Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the facebook API to get the feeds from a public page-

```
/PAGE_ID/feed
```

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Shadowfax.sahil%2Ffeed)